# Is Razor sharper than Ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, razor

I know jQuery is currently everybody's darling hammer (truth be told, I'm enamored with it, too), but I'm wondering if dynamically generating html might be more elegantly, or more easily, done using Razor/C#. For example, to update a page, consider this Razor pseudocode:

```
@{
   var divContent = functions.getDivContent("Platypus");

   if(IsPost)
   {
      divContent = functions.getDivContent(request[mammalName]);
   }
   else
   {
      ;//anything?
   }
}
```

//The getDivContent() function in functions (not shown) returns dynamically generated html

HTML pseudocode:

```
<body>
<form method="POST" action="" >
  <input type="Select" name="mammalName" ... />
</form>
  <div>@divContent</div>
</body>
```

jQuery pseudocode:

```
$('mammalName').selectionChanged() {
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Doing all of this in a jQuery function, such as using json data and calling .getJson(), would obviate the need for a complete page refresh, but in either case the server has to be queried for data, so I don't know if that's really such an advantage, especially in the case (mine) where the part of the page being refreshed is the lion's share of the page.

Is there a flaw in my thinking/design? Is there a compelling reason to choose jQuery over Razor here?

Comment: The advantage is not having to re-request all of your page assets. For every http request you make, all of the meta data (cookies and http headers) also get sent. Generally a site that uses ajax rather than a full page reload will feel more responsive to the end user.

Comment: jQuery runs on the client. Razor runs on the server. Apples and oranges.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, but calling .getJson() with jQuery still requires the server to be accessed, correct?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, the question isn't about whether or not to use jQuery/AJAX, but rather whether to return JSON or HTML from your AJAX call. If that's what you're asking, then there's nothing wrong at all with using jQuery/AJAX to request a partial from MVC, and letting Razor build the HTML and return it as HTML, then the AJAX result handler would simply dump that HTML where it belongs. So the two technologies can be used together.

Comment: @ClayShannon: Of course, but you can't "compare" an app that depends on client code to one that does not. The differences in structure will be huge.

Comment: You can compare using ajax to not using ajax on a very basic level. One will require reloading the page, the other won't. Sure, there are structural differences, but you can still compare the performance and the end user experience of the two different methods of delivering content.

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of validation you're looking for here.  Can you perform this one very specific task in two different ways using two different technologies?  Yes, and undoubtedly many more ways using many more technologies.  Does this have any bearing on the technologies themselves?  Not at all.  There is no "choose jQuery over Razor" any more than there is a "choose a screwdriver over a hammer."  You use the tools you have to build what you need to build.  The important part is to use them correctly and build something that's clear and easy to maintain, regardless of the tools.

Comment: Main reason I like AJAX is because I can keep lots of stuff in memory, session state if you will, and not have to keep it in valuable RAM on my server or send it back and forth with every update.

Comment: @eselk: `"keep lots of stuff in memory, session state"` ... `"not have to keep it in valuable RAM on my server"` - I don't think you're entirely clear on what "memory" or "session state" are.  Or on what AJAX does, for that matter.

Comment: @joe: I don't believe jQuery knows about MVC - unless you use knockout.js or something like that, maybe; I'm just talking about straight/raw jQuery.

Comment: @Jon: In either scenario, client-side code is used. In the "Razor" scenario, to fire the form submit, otherwise to also get the data and process it.

Comment: @KevinB: As what is changing is approximately 90% of the page (in my case), I don't see a big difference in "performance and the end user experience."

Comment: When I say to have jQuery talk to MVC, I just mean that it uses AJAX to make a request to `/MyController/MyAction` or however your bindings are set up - MVC receives the request and returns the contents of a partial view in the response, and the `success` action does something with that HTML. The two technologies are talking to each other without knowing about each other. jQuery thinks it's just talking to "some web server" and MVC thinks it's just returning "some response".

Comment: @Joe: Ah, I see; I'm not at all sure I will use MVC in this project, though. I agree with its value for larger projects, but is probably overkill for this personal project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are definitely things to consider when choosing to change pages using ajax or to change pages using a whole page reload.

performance-wise, using ajax will always come out on top because you're only requesting the entire page once, and then using ajax to request partials.

As far as maintenance, you don't actually need to change anything server-side to use ajax rather than Razor. The only added maintenance will be coding your client-side code to properly handle the fact that the page isn't going to reload.

If you used Ajax, you could optimize your requests FOR ajax, making your pages return only the needed content rather than the entire page, further improving performance. This comes at a slight cost to maintenance because it's adds another layer of complexity, however, if done properly, is easy to maintain.

UX wise, ajax will generally be better due to not having to reload the page. There is a loss of back-button functionality unless you also code that into your client-side ( also not very difficult ).

If you add SEO into the equation, things get a bit more difficult unless you coded your site FIRST to work without ajax, then added ajax functionality on top of it that way the crawlers can still access the entire site without ajax.

Comment: Can you expound on the last paragraph? How does Ajax affect SEO?

Comment: web crawlers typically don't use javascript (however, some do have minimal javascript capabilities), therefore any content that you deliver using javascript may not be available to search engines unless you provide another way for said content to be accessed.